# If the first element contains any zero, than my program is behaving in an undesired way

Tags: c++, string, vector, stringstream

What is wrong with this. Everything is working except the first element if the first element contains any zero. e.g. input -> 100 output -> 10 input->6030 output->630.

#### Question:

- Input Format

  The first and only line consists of n integers separated by commas.
- Output Format

  Print the integers after parsing it.

#### Code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> parseInts(string str) {
    // Complete this function
    stringstream ss(str);
    char ch;
    vector<int> v;
    int s;
    int i = 0;
    ss >> ch;
    cout << ch;
    while(ss >> i){
        v.push_back(i);
        ss >> ch;
    }    
    return v;
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    vector<int> integers = parseInts(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
        cout << integers[i] << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because it'll bite you eventually: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696) and [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/364696) should be high on your reading list.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ss >> ch;
> cout << ch;
> ```

The problem is here where you extract 1 char from the input stream before going into the loop and reading the rest. Also the way you have written the code is that a number is made of only a single digit because you can only read in 1 digit into a `char`.

If the input is a comma separated list of integers on a single line it is better to read in the whole line using [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and parse the line. You can specify the delimiter as the third parameter, and convert each string read to an integer using [std::stoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/). This will also allow you read in numbers containing more than one digit.

So try changing parseInts() as follows:

```
std::vector<int> parseInts(string str) {
    // Complete this function
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::string number;

    while (getline(ss, number, ','))
    {
        v.push_back(std::stoi(number));
    }

    return v;
}
```

One thing to note is the use of `>>operator` vs `getline`. The former will read until a space or newline while the latter will read a whole line. You are only able to read in the whole line using `>>` if it doesn't contain any spaces.

Comment: You shouldn't use `std::stoi` without using the second parameter to check the whole string has been parsed

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with this

You're reading from the string stream in a wrong manner.

To understand why you got 630 output for 6030 input, dry run your code. You're reading a character `ch` from stream so `ch` is assigned the value `'6'`. Now you're again reading from stream in while loop using variable `i` but `i` is an integer and so `"030"` is converted to `30(int)` and you finally get `630` as output.

Note that for cases like 678, 5, 10, etc. you'll get the correct output but not for all test cases.

Here's one correct way to do it:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> parseInts(std::string str) {
    std::stringstream whole_str(str);
    std::string integer_str;
    int integer;
    std::vector<int> v;
    while(whole_str >> integer_str){ // Read 1 integer(string) at a time
        std::stringstream one_int(integer_str);
        one_int >> integer; // Read and convert string to int
        v.push_back(integer);
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    std::string str{"100 200 5060 2040"};
    std::vector<int> integers = parseInts(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << integers[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output

```
100
200
5060
2040
```

Comment: `string str( "100 200 5060 2040" )` and the return is the __vector__ of integers.

Comment: I thought the author wanted digits in the vector. Thanks for correcting me. I've updated my answer.